# Render sub-component error using React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm following the React.js Facebook from [this tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html).
I added a more LikeButton component here:

```
var LikeButton = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
  return {liked: this.props.liked, id: this.props.id};
},
handleClick: function(event) {
  // post to server using ajax here
  this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked, id: this.prop.id});
},
render: function() {
var text = this.state.liked ? 'like' : 'unlike';
return (
  <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
    You {text} this. Click to toggle.
  </p>
);
}});
```

and then i put the component inside the comment block:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
      return <div>
      <Comment author={comment.author}>
      {comment.content}</Comment><LikeButton liked={comment.liked} id={comment.id} / </div>;
    });
```

At last i use setInterval in CommentBox to realtime update using polling.

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  }
React.renderComponent(
  <CommentBox url='comments.json' pollInterval={3000}/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

When i click like, the LikeButton component could render correctly, but when using setInterval, in server side, i manually changed the liked attribute of a comment, but the LikeButton component couldn't render correctly.
Do you know how to fix the problem ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you getting any errors, and if so, can you post them?

Comment: Also, check out the React team's post about [Props in getInitialState is an anti-pattern](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) to refactor your `LikeButton`. Your `LikeButton` shouldn't store any state; it should work with `props` only and let the state live in `CommentBox`.

Comment: Suppose i have a Component tree with 3 deep levels, as you said, if i want to handle state in the deepest child, i have to pass callback through to the root component ? I guess we must organize the components to at less level as possible.

Comment: ssorallen's response here is correct, and it's fairly typical to thread callbacks through multiple levels of components when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist on server side you are only setting the state so change your handleClick function like this using [**`axios`**](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/)

```
handleClick: function(event) {
  // post to server using ajax here
  this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked, id: this.prop.id});
  liked = this.state.liked;
  id = this.prop.id;
  axios.post('/YOUR_LIKE_UNLIKE_API_END_POINT', {
    liked: liked,
    id: id
  }).catch(function (error) {
    this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked, id: this.prop.id});
  });
},
```